# Free Trial Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to try the 2013 and 2011 versions of Dynamics CRM Online for that, I searched the internet but I found nothing.

I want to know if you have links to get these versions,

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't get Dynamics CRM 2011 or 2013 online, only 2015 and soon it will be 2016. CRM online is updated to the latest version soon after it is released.

Answer (score 0):

90-day trial versions of CRM 2011 and CRM 2013 **On Premise** are still available.

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27822)
[Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40341)